# What is the cause of spontaneous scattered errors in custom functions in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a fairly large spreadsheet that heavily uses custom functions for its functionality. This has been up and running without issue for a month, but today about 10-20% of the cells that use a custom function throw an error. If I remove and re-enter the formula the error goes away, but when reloading the sheet the same happens again. The errors are not in the same position every time. No part of the custom functions is stochastic.

I have tried copying the sheet over (the error remains, in different random places), and I have tried wrapping the entire custom functions in a try/catch block to see if I could change anything, but the errors remained the same. They are all the default error of "Internal error executing the custom function."

Is it possible that my custom functions are taking too much of Google's compute, timing out in some fashion? Is there a known bug? I'd love to know.

Comment: Have you tried to split the sheet onto a sample sheet with the same custom functions? Your assumption might be correct, due to the amount of cells that you could be running the functions might be affecting the whole performance of the functions in the sheet for being near the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause is that your custom functions take more than 30 seconds to execute. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values) tells:

> A custom function call must return within 30 seconds. If it does not, the cell will display an error: *Internal error executing the custom function.*

Another possible cause may be that you are using a very large number of spreadsheet formulas that call custom functions. To improve performance, you may want to array enable those functions. See these [custom function optimization tips](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization).

Yet another possible cause is that Google's servers are having a bad day. See [issue 36763283](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763283).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The issue has now (momentarily?) resolved itself, so it certainly seems like the servers were having a bad day. That having been said, do you know if the 30 seconds is per function or in total? Or is it parallelized in such a way that those are not really distinct? I cannot imagine any of the functions taking more than a fraction of a second, but in total... For now I'll optimize, which is certainly possible, I just didn't realize I had hit the point where that was needed.

Comment: Each function has its own copy of the runtime environment to itself during its 30 seconds of fame. When you open a spreadsheet and custom function formulas recalculate, they get evaluated one by one.